# Exchange mailbox default folders not in english

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

When I add new mailbox to Exchange 2010 (SBS 2011), for some reason default folders are in localized language, instead of English. Funny thing is that when we add mailboxes by adding a new user, folders are in English as they should be.

How to get default folders in English (in the first place), and how to rename or update these current folders? Is there a catch to do this from EMS?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Outlook system folders names assigned according to language of Outlook client used for first connection (profile creation). This folders cant be renamed.

To reset system folders names in English if it created with other language run Outlook with this user profile with **/resetfoldernames** commandline switch after changing the user interface language to English or installing a different language (English) version of Outlook.

Comment: Soon as I have created new mailbox, I have opened it using OWA and selecte Enlish as default language. Since I am not using Outlook, how can I reset folder names?

Comment: Seems no ways to reset folder names using OWA, just "Outlook.exe /resetfoldernames". But if you use the only OWA - try to set PC locale **and** IE language preferences to English before starting OWA first time...

Comment: Oh... Since you using Exchange 2010 and OWA - you can try to configure default language for whole Outlook Web App as described in this MS article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997435.aspx

Comment: Found a solution. In OWA there is an option "Rename default folders so their names match the specified language" under Options > Settings > Regional!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it via PowerShell cmdlet Set-MailboxRegionalConfiguration. Details are here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2826855/folder-names-are-incorrect-or-are-displayed-in-an-incorrect-language-i